# Command to add IIS6 Management Compatibility role in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, batch-file, iis-6

I have tried adding IIS6 Management Compatibility role in IIS7 through the following command but it is not working. For rest of the roles same format have worked. Any ideas?

Used commands:

```
start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS6-MetabaseCompatibility;
start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-IIS6MetabaseCompatibility;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally for windows features you can use the DISM too from command line. Reference Here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744382(WS.10).aspx

Use the command line

```
Dism /online /Get-Features
```

To browse for available features. Pick the one you like!

```
Dism /online /enable-feature /FeatureName:[yourfeaturehere]
```